# How to keep Windows desktop hotkey from taking focus

Tags: windows, winapi

I try to create a program that puts the active window in the top-left quarter of the screen. I currently use [GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx) and move it with [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx).

This works when I have my Windows Explorer open and double-click on my program. It then moves the Explorer top-left.

The problem is: how do I use this with a hotkey. I tried to put a link of my program on the desktop, then assign that a shortcut, e.g. Ctrl+Shift+1.
When I now open the Windows Explorer and use my hotkey, the Explorer does not move, it loses focus. It seems that the hotkey will run the program (which itself does not create a window) and makes it the foreground window.

How can I achieve what I want, is there a way for my program to not take focus (if that is what is happening) or is it possible via the Win API to find out the previously active window?

Comment: To summarize: Your issue is, that you are implementing a hotkey by creating a shortcut, and assigning it a hotkey. Pressing the hotkey causes the Shell to launch the process the shortcut references. This eventually causes the foreground thread to change. Solution: Don't use a shortcut to implement a hotkey. Use the dedicated API instead.

Comment: [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetForegroundWindow` is allowed to return NULL.

I would suggest that you actually create a little 1x1 pixel window and then when this window is activated you hide it and wait in a little loop (with a timeout) until `GetForegroundWindow` returns something else.

Because the taskbar and other shell windows can have focus you should make sure the returned HWND looks like a "normal" window by verifying that it at least has the `WS_CAPTION` and `WS_VISIBLE` styles (and not `WS_MINIMIZED`).

If you want to handle the case where the foreground window is not a "normal"  application window you could fall back to using [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) to find a suitable window but you need to be even more strict when inspecting the styles. You don't want to perform your action on always-on-top tool windows etc.

Comment: This works, creating a window, then minimizing it with ShowWindow will put focus on the window that was active when hitting the hotkey.

Comment: No need to poll the foreground window. [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) can register for [EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066.aspx) notifications.